# C Ansi Memory allocation closures

Tags: c, scope

I have this stuff:

*compiled with `gcc a.c -o a`*

```
// a.c
int main() {
    int a;   
    if (1) { 
        int b;
    }
    b = 2;
}
```

In console I will have the follow error:

```
a.c:7:4: error: ‘b’ undeclared (first use in this function)
a.c:7:4: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

All variables in C Ansi declared inside conditions will be closured to that scope?

Comment: b is only declared within the if statement.  You'll have to declare it outside the braces if you want to use it in main.

Comment: Yes. What did you expect?

Comment: @mathk It's only for knowledge. In JavaScript, for example, i Will have `var main = function () {
  if (1) {
     var a  = 1;
  }
  console.info(a);
}();` with another behavior

Comment: Yes the Javascript scoping is "kind of broken". :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certainly it has to throw an error.

The `{` and `}` braces are used to define a block which gives the block a new `scope`. 
And hence all the things defined or created inside a scope cannot be accessed outside that scope.

But you can access the members of the outer scope in a block if that block encloses some other blocks.

i.e

```
int main()
{
 int a;
 {
   int b;
    {
      int c;
      b = c;  // `b` is accessible in this innermost scope.
      a = c;  // `a` is also accessible.
    }
   // b = c;  `c` is not accessible in this scope as it is not visible to the 2nd block
   b = a;  // `a` is visible in this scope because the outermost block encloses the 2nd block.
 }
// a = b; outermost block doesn't know about the definition of `b`. 
// a = c; obviously it is not accessible.
return 0;
}
```

And, since `{}` are used in `if`'s ,`for`,`while`,`do-while` and `switch` constructs they define a new scope for each of them when used.

This is one good mechanism in which you can limit the visibility of `data` members in `C` where the `definition/declaration` of variables  is only allowed at the start of a block before any executable statement is encountered.

Answer (score 3):

b is local to the scope of that conditional. In order to use it, you will need to declare it before the loop. The most logical place would be right with a at the top of the function.

Comment: @alk oops, sorry I meant if statement.

Answer (score 0):

`b` is a local variable to `if` block, because you have defined it in a block (`if`) inside the `main()` block.
It is not visible beyond this `if` block, and that's the reason it is giving the error: `b undeclared (first use in this function)`. Declare `b` just after `a`(not necessary).

```
int a, b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not declare the variable b. b is a local variable you need to declare it inside the main block. This would not work outsite if block.

try something like this:-

```
int main() {
    int a;
    int b;   
    if (1) { 
        //....
    }
    b = 2;
}
```